# Dash filter df based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I like to filter my df based on dates. What I'm aiming for is to have a calendar wherein I can choose the dates from and based on the dates chosen, the df will filter the result, which is the sum of the same values (in this case, 'Name'). Here's how my df looks like.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

raw = [['tom', 10, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['tom', 5, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['nick', 15, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['nick', 8, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['juli', 14, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')],['juli', 7, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')],
       ['tom', 8, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['tom', 3, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['nick', 4, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['nick', 1, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')],['juli', 12, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['juli', 6, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['Name', 'Apples Gathered', 'date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#App layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        min_date_allowed=dt(2021, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2021,1,5),
    ),
])
dash_table.DataTable(
       id='datatable',
       columns=[
            {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
            {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'},
            {'id': 'date', 'name': 'date'}],

        data = df.to_dict('records'),
)

@app.callback(
       [Output('datatable', 'data'), Output('datatable', 'columns')],
       [Input('datepicker', 'start_date'),
       Input('date-picker', 'end_date')]
)
def update_table(start_date, end_date):
    #dff = [(df['date'].dt.date.astype(str) > start_date) & (df['date'].dt.date.astype(str) < end_date)]
    data = (df.groupby(['Name']).sum())
    fdata = data.to_dict('records')
    columns = [
            {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
            {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'}]
    return fdata, columns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I run that code, only the calendar comes up, my df doesn't. How do I fix the callback function so that my df would show up as well, which result I can filter based on the dates.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='datatable',
    columns=[
        {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
        {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'},
        {'id': 'date', 'name': 'date'}],

    data=df.to_dict('records')
)
```

is defined outside of the `layout`. Copying and pasting it into the `html.Div` element for example should display it in your app.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        min_date_allowed=dt(2021, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2021,1,5),
    ),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable',
        columns=[
            {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
            {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'},
            {'id': 'date', 'name': 'date'}],

        data=df.to_dict('records')
    )
])
```

Comment: My df showed up on the page, however, the date column is still there. I want the final df to be just 'Name' and 'Apples Gathered',  dates should be manipulated thru the calendar.